# How to get all records without duplicate

Tags: sql, duplicates

Hello everyone I'm trying to get all records without duplicate.

Here my sample database records.

```
   (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
   -----------------------------------------------
   (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
   (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
   (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java'),
   (4, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java')  !!This line should not appear after SQL result
```

What I want to get with SQL

```
   (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
   -----------------------------------------------
   (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
   (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
   (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java'),
```

Here is my SQL snippet for this subject.

```
select productName 
from ForgeRock
WHERE productName in (select productName from ForgeRock group by productName having count(*)>1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c924/121

How can I get all elements without duplicates ? Thanks for helpings.

Comment: Are you trying to delete duplicates or just query and remove them?  If the former, then a simple google "delete duplicates mysql" will probably give you lots of answers to the question.

Comment: I don't want to delete them. Only I want to show ? How many values added database. From this sample, I want to get count 3 but my SQL query give me 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you must use DISTINCT

```
select distinct productName,description from ForgeRock;
```

And this is mi result on fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c924/132

Comment: Doing so you will not be able to retrieve the `id` field, which is different for each row even in a set of duplicate ` (`productName`, `description`) `

Answer (score 3):

One method is to get data of minimum id

```
select min(`id`),`productname`,`description` from forgerock
group by `productname`, `description`
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular requirement on the value of the id ?

A simple `MIN()` function would do the trick

```
SELECT MIN(`id`),
  `productName`,
  `description`
FROM ForgeRock
GROUP BY `productName`, `description`
```

Comment: When I write your code to sqlFiddle, It gives me weird results.  you can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c924/126

Comment: I'm checking on my phone (yay blocking proxy), but it seems you replaced my backquotes ` with simple quotes '. Can you check ?

Comment: Yes with backquates sqlfiddle didn't work. sqlfiddle work with simple quotes.

Comment: It works with backquotes as well, it's part of the MySQL syntax. Are you sure you are using the 0x60 character ?